# Usando FileServer para compartilhar arquivos

Tags: http, golang

Estou aprendendo Golang e para praticar estou fazendo alguns pequenos "projetos", a minha ideia é apenas compartilhar uma pasta do meu Windows ou algum arquivo atraves da minha rede local wifi utilizando o pacote net/http do Golang. Utilizei esse pequeno codigo abaixo para "upar" uma pasta e depois poder acessar no meu celular ou notebook atraves do endereço de ip.

```
    import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("C:\\VIDEOS")))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}
```

O codigo funciona e consigo acessar os arquivos pelo navegador no meu PC, porem eu gostaria de saber como posso "liberar" acesso para outros dispositivos na minha rede acessarem os arquivos tambem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você executar o seu código go, o Windows vai te pedir permissão para que outros dispositivos na sua rede privada possam acessar essa porta (8080). Basta você permitir que ela ficará acessível.

Na hora de acessar, ao invés de você utilizar o endereço *localhost* + porta, você terá de utilizar o endereço IP do se computador nessa rede mais a porta. Para saber qual é o IP, basta acessar o *Command Prompt* e usar o comando `ipconfig/all`.

Comment: Resolvido o problema amigo valeu pela ajuda.